# How to push a div (say div1) using another div(div2) if div1 is fixed in upper position until div2 come below it while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have to seen the telegram web or app page.  while scrolling the the old chats the date are sticked to the top . when chats with new date comes , The div of new date push the div of old date on upper side without going over it.

[image]

See, here the div of 18 april  push the div of 16 push upper side and get fixed there.
How to get the exact same behaviour .
Can it be done using only CSS . Does it also require javascript. if yes please write the example code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working as expected?

Comment: I tried to implement this functionality using position : sticky on class=date which is assigned to every date div. through this the second div is not pushing the first div up  but just go above it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/sarraayush/pen/PoLKvwR
the above link describes what i have implemented

Answer (score -1):

Well ... although the date tags are controlled by the scroll, they have completely different behaviour. They should be in 2 separate containers for starters. If you don't want to deal with the transforms from nesting.

Beyond that, you are looking at a pure display programming problem so, yes, you need javascript. As for an example, there are many ways to skin this particular cat.

Comment: can you make edit to this below code or share me the new code that implement telegram date like effect. 
https://codepen.io/sarraayush/pen/PoLKvwR
the above link describes what i have implemented